# Validation when create or update a password field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I have created a `PartialView _CreateOrUpdate` user. But when I update information user I don't want to display the **validate password** field. I want to disable it when updating a user.

How can I do it?

My view model:

```
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "this field is required."), DisplayName("Password")]
   public string Password { get; set; }
```

My CreateOrUpdate view:

```
    <label class="control-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)</label>
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
        <span class="help-inline">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a model field required in one view and optional in another. Create separate models and views, perhaps using some inheritance and partials you can reduce code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can empty the span "help-inline" in your view, and then have a javascript like

```
if(update == false) { 
     $('.help-inline').html('@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password');
}
else {
     $('.help-inline').html('');
}
```